# Fetch data from varbinary coumn using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT CAST(binaryColname AS VARCHAR(5000)) FROM tableName
```

The above query is not not fetching the actual data properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CAST(binaryColname AS VARCHAR(max)) FROM tableName

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),binaryColname,2) FROM tableName
```